# How to properly execute this ajax request with Django?

Tags: python, html, django

I made a page with form that has a few fields from a model called *EmployeeWorkAreaLog*, the first field being where a person enters their Employee #, which is tied to a separate model called *Salesman* that has all the main data for verification. I made this function **get_employee_name()**, which returns the name based on the *Employee #* from the other model, but I'm not sure how to display it in the page, right on the top, without refreshing after the person tabs/clicks out into the next field in the form?

I'm not too familiar with html, but I was reading an ajax request would do the trick, but I'm not sure how to approach this. Below you can see what I attempted, but I'm not sure how to handle the *success* or how to properly insert it into the html.

This is basically so the person knows that the Employee # they entered matches their name before proceeding to fill the rest out.

**views.py**

```
class EnterExitArea(CreateView):
    model = EmployeeWorkAreaLog
    template_name = "operations/enter_exit_area.html"
    form_class = WarehouseForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        emp_num = form.cleaned_data['adp_number']
        area = form.cleaned_data['work_area']
        station = form.cleaned_data['station_number']

        if 'enter_area' in self.request.POST:
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info)

        elif 'leave_area' in self.request.POST:
            form.save()
            EmployeeWorkAreaLog.objects.filter(adp_number=emp_num).update(time_out=datetime.now())
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info)


def get_employee_name(request):
    adp_number = request.GET.get('adp_number')
    employee = Salesman.objects.get(adp_number=adp_number)
    employee_name = employee.slsmn_name
    return employee_name
```

**models.py**

```
class EmployeeWorkAreaLog(TimeStampedModel, SoftDeleteModel, models.Model):
    adp_number = models.ForeignKey(Salesman, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, help_text="Employee #", null=True, blank=False)
    work_area = models.ForeignKey(WorkArea, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=False, help_text="Work Area", related_name="work_area")
    station_number = models.ForeignKey(StationNumber, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, help_text="Station", related_name="stations", blank=True)
    time_in = models.DateTimeField(help_text="Time in", null=True, blank=True)
    time_out = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, help_text="Time out", null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.adp_number
```

**forms.py**

```
class WarehouseForm(AppsModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeWorkAreaLog
        widgets = {
            'adp_number': ForeignKeyRawIdWidget(EmployeeWorkAreaLog._meta.get_field('adp_number').remote_field, site),
        }
        fields = ('adp_number', 'work_area', 'station_number')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.adp_number
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'enter-exit-area/$', EnterExitArea.as_view(), name='enter_exit_area'),
    path('ajax/get-employee-name', views.get_employee_name, name='ajax_get_employee_name'),
]
```

**enter_exit_area.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block main %}
    <form id="warehouseForm" action="" method="POST" get-employee-name-url="{% url 'operations:ajax_get_employee_name' %} novalidate >
        {% csrf_token %}

        <div>
            <div>
                {{ form.adp_number.help_text }}
                {{ form.adp_number }}
            </div>
            <div>
                {{ form.work_area.help_text }}
                {{ form.work_area }}
            </div>
            <div>
                {{ form.station_number.help_text }}
                {{ form.station_number }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit" name="enter_area" value="Enter">Enter Area</button>
                <button type="submit" name="leave_area" value="Leave">Leave Area</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script>
        $("#id_adp_number").change(function () {
            var url = $("#warehouseForm").attr("get-employee-name-url");
            var adp_num = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: {
                    'adp_number': adp_num
                },
                success: function (response) {

                }
            });
        });
    </script>

{% endblock main %}
```

Below is part of the model where all the original data is stored.
**alldata/models.py**

```
class Salesman(models.Model):
    slsmn_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    adp_number = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: So you want the employee's name to automatically appear somewhere once they enter their ADP number? Without refreshing the page?

Comment: @J.Behnken  Yes. Kinda how like when you're creating an account and after you finish typing the username you want, and you click on the next box you want to fill out, it either tells you "Username XXXXX is already taken", but instead it just says the name itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try something along these lines:

1) Add a route like this to **urls.py**

```py
path('get-employee-name/<int:adp_num>/', views.get_employee_name, name='employee_name')
```

2) You need a way to reference the ADP number form field, so give it an HTML `id` attribute in your **models.py**

```py
class WarehouseForm(AppsModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeWorkAreaLog
        widgets = {
            'adp_number': ForeignKeyRawIdWidget(EmployeeWorkAreaLog._meta.get_field('adp_number').remote_field, site, attrs={'id':'adp_number_field'}),                                                
        }
        fields = ('adp_number', 'work_area', 'station_number')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.adp_number
```

(adding `attrs={'id':'adp_number_field'}` inside `ForeignKeyRawIdWidget()` though not entirely sure if that's the correct placement.)

You also need an HTML element that will contain and display the employee's name, so somewhere outside the form, add an HTML element like this:
`<p id='employee_name'></p>`

3) Use AJAX to detect a change in the ADP Number field, like you did, and send a POST to the URL above, which returns an employee name.

```js
        $("#adp_number_field").change(function () {
            var adp_num = $(this).val();
            var url = 'get-employee-name/' + adp_num;

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type:'post',    
                data: {
                    'adp_number': adp_num
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    employee_name = data;
                    $('#employee_name')[0].innerHTML = employee_name;
                }
            });
        });
```

I didn't test any of this, this was just off the top of my head, but there should be enough here to get you on the right track.